# Hide ion items in side menu after login in Ionic/AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm new in Angular and Ionic. I'm trying to hide some ion items from the side menu based on the login status but it doesn't work. Do you know why?

This is the app.js file - it's basicly the default app.js file from the ionic side menu template.

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {    
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    });
    })

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('top');
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        }
      }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('app.login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: './templates/login.html',
                controller: 'AppCtrl'
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('app.single', {
        url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
                controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
            }
        }
    });   
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
    });
```

> This is the controllers file - After the login form is submitted and
>   it passes the validation it will call  loginSuccess() function which
>   will set the "isLogged" variable to true. Now the side menu elements
>   which have ng-show attributes should appear but they don't. If i
>   insert a console.log in the loginSuccess function it will show that
>   the variable has the value true but still it doesn't work.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('starter.controllers', []);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout,  $state) {       
        $scope.bothErrors = false;
        $scope.emailError = false;
        $scope.isLogged = false;
        $scope.loginData = {};

        $scope.doLogin = function () {
            if($scope.validateEmail($scope.loginData.username)) {
                if($scope.loginData.username == 'george@wgeorge.ro' && $scope.loginData.password == '1234') {
                    $scope.loginSuccess();
                }else{
                    $scope.bothErrors = true;
                    $scope.emailError = false;
                }
            }else{
                $scope.emailError = true;
            }
        };

        $scope.loginSuccess = function () {
            $state.go('app.dashboard');
            $scope.bothErrors = false;
            $scope.isLogged = !$scope.isLogged;
        };

        $scope.logOut = function(){
            $scope.isLogged = !$scope.isLogged;
            $state.go('app.login');
        };

        $scope.validateEmail = function (email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        };
    }); 
}());
```

This is the sidemenu html file

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-title>
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo">
            </ion-nav-title>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/dashboard">
                    Acasa
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item ng-show="showProfile" menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    item1
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    item2
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    item3
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item ng-show="isLogged" menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                    item4
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: make isLogged as rootscope..!

Comment: You need to change $scope.isLogged to $rootScope.isLogged. let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked. I've tried this before and it worked like this: first i logged in and it didn't work then i logged in again and it worked. Each time i had to do that. The difference now is that i commented out the initial declaration $rootScope.isLogged = false. I've read that before you use a scope variable you must declare it first. Why did it work like this?